col-n overrides col-sm but not col-sm-n for small screens

When a cell is defined as:



<div class= "col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-4"> ... </div>



For small screens, the cell is taking 2/12th of the width (as per col-sm-2).

But when a cell is defined as:



<div class= "col-4 col-sm col-md-4"> ... </div>



For small screens, the cell is taking 4/12th of the width (as per col-4).
I understand the first case, but not the second.
Why "col-sm" is not getting considered in second case for small screens?
I know that col-4 means 4/12th of the width for all screen size.
But in the first case, for small screens, col-4 got overridden by col-sm-2, then why not in second case col-4 got overridden by col-sm for small screens?

After doing few hit and trials, I found that col-abc-n will override col-xyz. Even if xyz is larger than abc.
For example, if a column is defined as:
<div class= "col-md-5 col-lg"> ... </div>

Even if col-lg generally means col-lg-12, for large screens (or extra large screens), width will be given according to col-md-5 and not col-lg.
But if the column was defined as:
<div class= "col-md-5 col-lg-12"> ... </div>

For large or extra large screen, column will get width according to col-lg-12, i.e. 12/12 th width of the row.

As you have not mentioned the space, col-sm will not take the entire space because col-4 and col-md-4 will override it. It is important to mention the space if you wanna set it different for that div.
For example, if you want to set it to take the entire screen, write col-sm-12.

On output I am seeing that for small screens, the cell is taking only 4/12th of the width, and not complete row. Can you please explain? I got to know from someone that col-sm works as col-sm-12. Then why doesn't it take the complete row? Why col-4 overrides col-sm for small screens? Strangely col-4 doesn't override col-sm-n for small screens.

I have updated my response, please read again.
